Passing ID from url link to javascript code
I'd like to do PDFViewer base on RESTful Services in APEX 19.2. I have IG where one column is file_name base on URL link:
javascript:apex.event.trigger(document, 'PDFViewer', [{id:'#ID#'}]); void(0);

After click file_name is executed dynamic action with belowe code:
let id = this.data.id;

async function getData(){
let afetch = await fetch(`https://------/ords/ap/doc/docs/${id}`);
let blob = await afetch.blob();
let blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
let pdfContainer = document.getElementById('pdfViewer');
pdfContainer.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src = blobUrl;
}

getData();

but I get an error: 404 NOT FOUND
from inspect:
GET https://------/ords/ap/doc/docs/ 404 (Not Found)
When I change ${id} for static value corresponding id, PDFViewer works. Any idea how to pass ID from IG to  javascript code?

Have you attempted to debug it? What do you see when you log this.data or this.data.id?

I found a solution. The issue was that, I've used IG. When I've change to IR everything works. Dubigging from IG returned this.Object  >data: {id: "#ID#"}
